# I have a hyperlink in my text and want to trigger my own code to send analytics when the link is pressed

Tags: events, google-analytics, handler, message, intercept

Basically I have a piece of text for example "Welcome to my website click **here** to read more"

The code works fine and the hyperlink works to send the user to the requires destination however I want to run code to see if users are actually pressing this button.

```
if (feed.getTextLong() != null && !feed.getTextLong().equals("")) {
        if (!feed.getTextLong().equals("")) {

            if(!feed.getUrl().equals("")) {

                tvFeedText.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                        feed.getTextLong() +
                                " <a href=\"" + feed.getUrl() + "\">Read more</a> "));
                tvFeedText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());


            }
```

As you can see above that is the code to create the sentence shown at the top obviously in a different format.

How can i intercept this code and receive a message to know that it has been done?

Thanks